# Show that if $L(u_i)=v_i$ for some finite set, and span$(u_i) \cap \ker(L)=0,$ then the set of v_i are independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I get that, if $c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n = 0,$ applying L to both sides gives that, $c_1u_1 + ... + c_nu_n \in \ker(L),$ so $c_1u_1 + ... + c_nu_n = 0$ but since we don't know if the $u_i$'s are independent or not, I'm not seeing why this implies that the $v_i$'s are independent.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Well I tried showing they are independent by showing that the sum of the u_i's is in the kernel, but I get stuck at this point.

Comment: I also tried showing that if the u_i's are dependent that more than one thing is in the kernel, but I can't seem to make this work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've offered enough conditions. I'll assume $L$ is linear mapping, at least $\Bbb Z$-linear map, and $\{u_i\mid i\in I\}$ is linear independent.

Then, if there exists $c_i$ such that $\sum_{i\in F}c_iv_i=0$. ($F\subseteq I$ is finite set.)

Then $u=\sum_{i\in F}c_iu_i$ is the element of $\text{span}(u_i)$, and $\ker L$. Why?

> $L(u)=L(\sum_{i\in F}c_iu_i)=\sum_{i\in F}c_iL(u_i)=\sum_{i\in F}c_iv_i=0$.

So $u=0$, because $\ker L\cap\text{span}(u_i)=0$. That means $\forall i\in F, c_i=0$.

Every non-trivial linear combination of $\{v_i\mid i\in I\}$ is non-zero. So $\{v_i\mid i\in I\}$ is linear independent.

Comment: Thank you! But isn't this only true if the set of u_i's is independent? We do not know this for sure in the problem I was given.